# Invertir un int

Tags: java

**Tengo este código que lo que hace es darle vuelta al número int, pero lo que no entiendo es como funciona la operación para darle vuelta, entonces mi duda es si me explcan como funciona el while**

```
package com.mycompany.tareasemana2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TareaSemana2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numero, invertido = 0, resto;
        Scanner consola = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce un número: ");

        numero = consola.nextInt();

        while (numero > 0) {
            resto = numero % 10;
            invertido = invertido * 10 + resto;
            numero /= 10;
        }

        System.out.println("Número invertido: " + invertido);
    }

}
```

Comment: debuguea para q te des cuenta

Comment: Perfecto, ya entiendo, gracias!

Comment: @Japv debugear sirve para una persona que ya conoce sobre el razonamiento intrinceco en un codigo de programacion, lo que el OP busca es que le explique ese razonamiento ... en este contexto el debuggear no le diara nada.

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover mmmm esta pregunta es de hace casi dos años

Comment: Si y me gusto... es un ejemplo practico de que no todas las respuestas requieren codigo ...

Answer (score 2):

Tomemos por ejemplo: 159

| numero inicial | resto | invertido | numero inicial siguiente |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 159 | resto = numero % 10; | invertido = invertido * 10 + resto; | numero /= 10; |
| 159 | `9 = 159 % 10` | `9 = (0*10) + 9` | `15 = 150 / 10` |
| 15 | `5 = 15 % 10` | `95 = (9*10) + 5` | `1 = 15 / 10` |
| 1 | `1 = 1 % 10` | `951 = (95*10) + 1` | `0 = 1 / 10` |

puedes ver que en el valor de invertido va tomando siempre el último digito del numero ingresado y posteriormente se va sumando el último digito (`resto`) del siguiente numero inicial. Por eso la formula `invertido = invertido * 10 + resto;` esta multiplicada por `10` y suma el `resto`. De esta forma va `girando` el número.

> El valor inicial siguiente como son de tipo int al dividir **15/10 = 1.5 -> 1** por ser int y por lo mismo **1/10 = 0.1 -> 0** por lo mismo

Espero te sirva saludos .

Answer (score 1):

***Que hace el Ciclo While?***

***Resp:***

***- Entrada del número:*** Primero, el programa solicita al usuario que ingrese un número entero.

***- [Bucle while](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_while_loop.asp) (`while(numero > 0){`):*** El bucle while se ejecuta mientras el valor de `numero` sea mayor que 0.

***- Cálculo del resto, [Operador modulo](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#floorMod(int,int)) (`numero % 10;`):*** En cada iteración del bucle, se calcula el resto de la división de `numero` entre 10 utilizando el operador de módulo %. Este resto corresponde al último dígito del número original.

***- Inversión del número (`invertido * 10 + resto`):*** Luego, se multiplica el valor actual de `invertido` por 10 y se le suma el resto calculado anteriormente. Esto se hace para construir el número invertido.

***- [Actualización del número original](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_Java/Operadores_de_asignaci%C3%B3n) (`numero /= 10`):*** Después de obtener el último dígito y agregarlo al número invertido, se actualiza el valor de `numero` dividiéndolo por 10. Esto elimina el último dígito del número original, ya que estamos trabajando de derecha a izquierda.

***- Repetición del proceso:*** Este proceso se repite hasta que `numero` sea menor o igual a 0. En ese punto, hemos invertido completamente el número original.

***- [Salida](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/system-out-println-in-java/) del número invertido (`System.out.println`):*** Una vez que el bucle while termina, se imprime el valor de invertido, que ahora contiene el número original pero invertido.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer] y también [CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido), saludos.

Comment: Gracias pero no uso ChatGPT para dar respuestas, podras verificar que he includo toda la documentacion que encontre de referencia para que el usuario pueda continuar su estudio y/o Ver los ejemplos adecuados.

Comment: @Jorgesys agradeceria borres ese negativo comentario sobre mi respuesta, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

1. Obtiene el resto de dividir el numero por 10 (osea el primer digito de la derecha):

`resto = numero % 10`.

2. Luego pone ese resultado al principio del numero "invertido":

`invertido = invertido * 10 + resto;`

3. Luego divide el numero por 10 para ir a por el siguiente digito

`numero /= 10;`

4. Como el numero es dividido por 10 en cada iteracion, va a llegar u momento en el que el numero va a ser menor a 0 (ej: 0,01232312) , ahi es cuando frena el bucle.

PD: Estos ejercicios son cruciales para que los razones solo.

---------------EDIT--------------------

Detalle imporante: Esto funciona con variables INT, debido al caesteo implicito que hay en en el calculo (numero /= 10;)